# How do I subdivide the content of a Select-Clause without losing its full result?

Tags: mysql

I have got a database containing events to happen on different days of the week.
I want to count the number of these events x and in another column next to it how many of a different events y happened simultaneously on every specific day of the week. Both, x and y, are from the same relation.

I tried a normal select statement with both count(x) and count(y) in it. However both columns appear to have the same number which certainly is not true.

Either both columns show the number of x and when I use a where clause: y=1 or y=0 both columns have the count for y.

Which construct is recommended instead of mine below?

```
select day, count(x), count(y)
from events
group by day
```

```
select day, count(event_ID), count(y=1)
from events
group by day
e.g.
event_ID= 1 or 2 or 23012 and y=1 or y=0 and day=Monday or day=Tuesday etc
```

```
desired answer format: Day || Count(**ALL** distinct x) || Count(y=1)
```

EDIT: I cannot add data because the file is too big. I also cannot sum the event x because every event x has an ID.

EDIT: Event x is basically the whole content of the events relation. Every row contains one event x.

Comment: can you please add your data to your question see [mre], also you can try SUM(evnt = A)

Comment: you can limit the number of rows by select only 2 days,. and also reducing it to the necessary columns

Comment: and SUM(event = id1) doesn't sum up the id it sums the comparison, 1 for true 0 for false

Comment: We'll be able to give you better advice if you show us a few rows of your data (certainly not all of it) and a sample of the result you want. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Please use sqlfiddle to create an example database with a few data and show your expected output. You don't need to insert all your data.

Comment: Why am I not allowed to ask questions anymore? I have seen questions here with a +100 rating which were equally formatted and with an equal amount of sample data. I think it is extremely unfair. This is a question which has never been asked here and someone blocked me from the forum just because he/she doesn't like my writing?